# How to remove blank space inside WKScrollView after change WKWebview frame height?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, wkwebview

How to remove the blank area after change WKWebview's frame height?  
I want change webview's height when keyboard show up, but after the frame height changed, there are an extra space below the HTML body. And the height of this extra blank area is about the height of keyboard.

Here is the code snippet:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.rx
.notification(UIApplication.keyboardDidShowNotification)
.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] keyboardConfig in
    if let userInfo = keyboardConfig.userInfo{
       let keyboardBounds = (userInfo["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgRectValue;
                
       self?.webView.snp.remakeConstraints({ make in
           make.left.right.top.equalToSuperview();
           /// remake from screen height to below height.
           make.height.equalTo(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - keyboardBounds.size.height);
       });
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Check how many time this is getting called.

Comment: @ShreeramBhat only one time

Answer (score 0):

Finally I still don't know how to remove this extra blank area, but I have figure out a workaround.
Since `WKScrollView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so the `UIScrollView Delegate` also works for `WKScrollView`;
Therefore the contentOffset can be force reseted in the UIScrollView `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. Code snippet is provided below.

```swift
/// Change webview frame when keyboard appear.
NotificationCenter.default.rx
.notification(UIApplication.keyboardDidShowNotification)
.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] keyboardConfig in
    if let userInfo = keyboardConfig.userInfo, let this = self {
        let keyboardBounds = (userInfo["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgRectValue;
        this.webView.snp.remakeConstraints({ make in
            make.left.right.top.equalToSuperview();
            /// remake from screen height to below height.
            make.height.equalTo(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - keyboardBounds.size.height);
        });
        let originalOffset = this.webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            this.webView.scrollView.contentOffset = originalOffset;
        }
    }
});
```

```swift
/// Force reset contentOffset when the contentOffset is out of HTML Body
extension YourWebviewVC: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    internal func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.adjustWebviewOffsetFor(scrollView);
    }
    
    private func adjustWebviewOffsetFor(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, animated: Bool = false){
        let currentY = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.height;
        if currentY > scrollView.contentSize.height{
            let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height;
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: maxOffset), animated: animated);
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
/// Don't forgot set webview scroolView's delegate, for example
self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
```

Comment: but won't this still show the empty space if the user scrolls? i am facing the same issue now but i need to eliminate the empty space